# How to change width in TemplateField using Eval

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview contains many Template-Fields.
I want to make the width of a label in my html source equal to a value saved in my database. Here is the code I am trying but it is not working:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label BackColor="#6699ff" Width="<%# 
           Eval("Status").ToString()  %>" runat="server">&nbsp;</asp:Label>
           <%# Eval("Status").ToString()  %>%
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Label acts like a Span after rendered as html. Span is a Inline Element so applying width to span will not take any effect on output.

Comment: as you can see in my code I just put a 'space' inside this label and I am trying to increase the label width to show progress.. If label cannot work, what I can use so I can see the effect on output? Thanks

Comment: You can try to check with my answer.

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know. Thanks @Naveen Gogineni

Comment: It does not work.. the error happens here: 
Width='<%# Eval("Status").ToString()  %>'
With single(') Compiler Error Message: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'
And with (") The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: you must use outer single quotes because of the inner double quotes in the Eval() : Try `Eval("Status","{0}px")`

Comment: or if `Status` represents a percentage use `Eval("Status","{0}%")`

Comment: Thanks this what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can do something like this:

```
span.gridLabel
{
    display:block;
    /*You can change to display:inline-block if you want Label and %Value in same line.*/
}
```

And your template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <span class="gridLabel" style='width:<%# Eval("Status").ToString()  %>px; Background:#6699ff'>&nbsp;</span>
           <%# Eval("Status").ToString()  %>%
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: In Item Template change Label with span and try it.